# AreaSerie con 2 lineas en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy necesitando hacer un grafico de AreaSerie en WPF pero que tenga 2 funciones graficadas.
Algo similar a la foto que adjunto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @christian. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que realices el [tour] y leas [ask]. Como verás, la idea es que, investigues la mejor solución que puedas encontrar, intentes solucionarlo y, si surgen dudas de temas específicos de código, puedas plantear un problema en concreto y bien específico. ¿Podrías ver si se te ocurre cómo [edit] la pregunta para que sea algo más específica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias evaluar

[Sparrow Toolkit](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/)

lo puedes agregar por nuget [Sparrow.Chart.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sparrow.Chart.Wpf/)

Este dispone del tipo de graficas que buscas, en el link tienes imagenes de los graficos que puede conseguir